# Perl, How to find and modify multiple expressions in a single string

Tags: regex, string, perl, string-substitution

I have a file that contains many lines like the following:

```
some text { {{7.718 1072.463} {7.718 1230.985} {15.724 1230.985} {15.724 1198.742} {15.759 1198.742} } {{7.702 1072.489} {7.702 889.858} {13.418 889.858} {13.418 887.367} {13.435 887.367} {13.435 887.376} {7.144 887.376} } } some more text
```

Each pair of values are X and Y coordinates.  For each line in the file, I want to find every X value and add a certain value (lets say 6.3) and print that new line.  The X value will always follow a { without any space.  I am able to get each X value in a single line with this while loop:

```
 while ($line=~/\{\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g) {
     $oldX=~s/\{//;
 }
```

But how can I add a value (like 6.3) to every X occurrence of X value I find the string?
I want the new string to look just like the original except each X value should be increased by 6.3.

Thank you for any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$line =~ s/\{\K(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/$1 + 6.3/ge` will replace each number immediately following a curly bracket (`{`) with the same number increased by 6.3.

The `\K` keeps the curly brace. The `/e` flag to `s///` evaluates the expression in the replacement part of the substitution. And `g` flag replaces every occurrence of the match.

If you need to match numbers that start with a dot (e.g. `.25`), try:

```perl
$line =~ s/\{\K(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)/$1 + 6.3/ge
```

You can replace 6.3 in the regex with the variable containing the amount to add.

Comment: Swapping delimiter `/` for `!` without a good reason is probably a bad idea and serves only as obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also only make use of `\K` and use the full match using `$&` in the replacement.

Using `\K` will reset the starting point of the reported match (forgets what is matched so far)

The pattern matches:

- `\{` Match `{`
- `\K` Forget what is matched until so far
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally match a dot and 1+ digits

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vnq5PM/1) or a [Perl demo](https://tio.run/##dc9LCoMwEAbgvacYRIoijOadVIoH6BVcNhTBF@qiRezVra/SLixZDPnI/OFvbFuIaSqf4BV5ZeECbleXFnr76GGAYVCoiAYSK4pcshE@QFmMRosZiEBF@ZEQo1FxuoswPzJu0THdo7XZomfQ2qAWetliyOe/DkAhk2oHJv6Akmsm4fx7X85asKzbraWbOHv1F3RRNmTX7Bb66TnDeQZp5J0gBIksutvEadq86v31fZBM0xs)

For example

```
$line =~ s/\{\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?/$& + 6.3/ge;
print($line);
```

Output

```
{ {{14.018 1072.463} {14.018 1230.985} {22.024 1230.985} {22.024 1198.742} {22.059 1198.742} } {{14.002 1072.489} {14.002 889.858} {19.718 889.858} {19.718 887.367} {19.735 887.367} {19.735 887.376} {13.444 887.376} } }
```

---

If you want to assert a closing `}` at the right, you can make use of a positive lookahead.

```
\{\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^{}]*})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQAbm2/1)

Comment: Swapping delimiter `/` for `~` without a good reason is probably a bad idea and serves only as obfuscation.

Comment: In recent perls you need to escape literal left braces https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2017/04/you-must-escape-the-left-brace-in-a-regex/

Comment: It's only one of the reasons, including the weird delimiter and not explaining what \K does. But, then, code that won't compile is usually a sufficient reason.